# Facebook test mvc application permission page redirecting

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I am recently started to learn the [facebook sdk](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/) . However, I went to run the test mvc3 application on a test facebook iframe app. changed appid,secret,app url. Homepage showing fine on facebook iframe, but the about page(which actually using the authentication implementation) is redirecting for permission, i gave it permission, and still redirects back to permission page again and again.. Did any of you faced same problem? How to solve this issue plz?

Regards

Comment: What version of the SDK are you using?  I had this problem on MVC3 until going to SDK version 4.2.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you really need to shift to 5.0 (if not) as i was getting similar problem and resolved by using their example and 5.0 sdk

Comment: hi, tried and faced this problem in the v 5.0 also at the first time i ran the app. After that, it bacame ok. Nothing needed to be done. COnfused with this behaviour :(

Comment: Extremely sorry i didnt get that  "After that, it bacame ok. Nothing needed to be done"

Comment: First time it didn't work. Then I ran the application again and it worked ok.